# hyperlink in gridview with procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have this page buscli.aspx

[image]

is working fine now the source of the griview is an storedprocedure

```
string valorC = "%" + TextBox1.Text + "%"; numo = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        switch (numo)
        { 
            case "Nome":  num3 = 1;  break;
            case "Endereço": num3 = 2; break ;
            case "Telefone": num3 = 3 ; break;
            case "Pedido": num3 = 4; break ;
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "cazacliente2";
        SqlParameter valor = new SqlParameter("@vbusca", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        SqlParameter num = new SqlParameter("@bo",SqlDbType.Int );
        valor.Value = valorC   ; num.Value = num3 ; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(valor); cmd.Parameters.Add(num);
        cmd.Connection = conex1;
        try
        {
            GridView1.EmptyDataText = "Nao se" + numo.ToString()  +"econtraron registros";
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }
        finally
        {
            conex1.Close();
            conex1.Dispose();
        }
```

but now i need to convert in hyperlink the column pedido, i have see many youtube samples but all are datasets  , i have try with any result with hyperlink field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use RowDataBound event of Gridview to manipulate how the data will be presented. Below is an example from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // Display the company name in italics.
      e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<i>" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "</i>";

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add a template column in the gridview and add a anchor tag. Kindly note you should use http:// to make the link work properly. Below is a sample. Here ColumnName and ColumnValue are the columns that are coming from the DataTable/List/Collection as a datasource.

```
<asp:templatefield>
<itemtemplate>
  <a href='<%string.Format("http://www.yourlink.com/page.aspx?id={0}",
  Eval("ColumnName"))%>' runat="server">Eval("ColumnValue")</a>
</itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```

I hope this will help you.